# Select constant text that is the same as a column name

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to select const text for an insert. However the text is the same as a column name and gets interpreted as such. How do I work around this?

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (a, b, c)
SELECT "a", a, b 
FROM Table2
```

If Table2 looks like:

```
a, b
1, 1
2, 2
```

I want the inserted columns to look something like:

```
"a", 1, 1
"a", 2, 2
```

But with this SQL query, it interprets "a" as column a, which is clearly *not* what I want.

Comment: `SELECT 'a', a, b FROM Table2` But why do you want all the rows to have the same value (`'a'`) in that column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Values in SQLite should be wrapped in single-quotes, like:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (a, b, c) 
SELECT 'a', a, b 
FROM Table2;
```

However, as @Ypercube asked in his comment, why do you want a column with the same value for every row?

Comment: To use as a flag/attribute for that data import. Like to mark some data type or the source of that data.